# Is path in Set-Cookie URL encoded?

Tags: http, character-encoding, cookies, http-response, url

I'm writing some code that sets cookies and I'm wondering about the exact semantics of the `Set-Cookie` header. Imagine the following HTTP header line:

```
Set-Cookie: name=value; Path=/%20
```

For with path does this set the cookie? `/` or `/%20`(unescaped) (`/%20` or `/%2520` escaped)?

The reason I'm asking is that I should support non-ASCII paths. Since HTTP header must only be ASCII my plan was to URL escape the path value but the HTTP specification is not as clear as I'd hoped for.

**Edit**

I know what Path is supposed to do. My question is: Is the value interpreted as percent encoded or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [standard to support IRIs](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3987.txt) states the character encoding for such URL must be UTF-8. It also states in [4.1.2.4 in HTTP State Management Mechanism](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6265.txt) that the path is that of the directory part of the URI (i.e. the encoded IRI). Eg. the directory '/å/' has Cookie path '/%C3%A5/' even though the response header states the content-type is ISO-8859-1.

%20 is a encoded space in UTF-8 charset, thus the cookie-path '/%20' is slash-space.

Answer (score 5):

**Syntax**

> setcookie(name,value,expire,path,domain,secure)
>
> path
>
> Optional. Specifies the server path of the cookie
>   If set to "/", the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If set to "/test/", the cookie will only be available within the test directory and all sub-directories of test. The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.

Source: [PHP setcookie() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp#gsc.tab=0)

[There is also a great existing SO answer around allowed characters in cookies (it talks about ASCII characters)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1969339/427684)

> What that document doesn't remember to say, because Netscape were terrible at writing specs, was that control characters (\x00 to \x1F plus \x7F) aren't allowed, and support for non-ASCII characters is left unspecified.
>
> What browsers do:
>
> - in Opera and Google Chrome, non-ASCII characters are encoded into cookies with UTF-8;
> - in IE, the machine's default code page is used (locale-specific and never UTF-8);
> - Firefox (and other Mozilla-based browsers) use the low byte of each UTF-16 code point on its own (so ISO-8859-1 is OK but anything else is mangled);
> - Safari simply refuses to send any cookie containing non-ASCII characters.
>
> So in practice you cannot use non-ASCII characters in cookies at all. If you want to use Unicode, control codes or other arbitrary byte sequences you must use an ad-hoc encoding scheme of your own choosing. Most popular is UTF-8-inside-URL-encoding (as produced by JavaScript's encodeURIComponent).

Comment: I don't use PHP and the function documentation does not say what happens to non-ASCII paths. I'm not talking about cookie names and values, I'm talking about cookie paths. I know I can't use non-ASCII. I'm just asking about the semantics of the path eg. is it assumed to be percent encoded or not.

Answer (score 1):

My intuition says that the path is an URL-encoded value (since it is a URL).

Why not test it? I created the following nginx config:

```
add_header Set-Cookie "k=v; path=/";
add_header Set-Cookie "f%2520o=ba%2520r; path=/qa%20x";
add_header Set-Cookie "f%2520o=ba%2520r; path=/qb%25x";
add_header Set-Cookie "Z%2520Z=Z%2520Z; path=/";
location ~ /q.* {
    try_files $uri /cookie.html;
}
```

The index page:

```
<iframe src="/qa%20x"></iframe>
<iframe src="/qa x"></iframe>
<iframe src="/qb%25x"></iframe>
<iframe src="/qb%2520x"></iframe>
<iframe src="/qb%20x"></iframe>
```

The cookie page is essentially writing `document.cookie`. Conclusion: the path is interpreted as a percent-encoded sequence (with automatic conversion of a space to `%20` as needed). I have tested it in Firefox and Chromium, both  browsers show the same behavior. Guess which browser is an exception of this... IE8 did not show the cookies from the percent-encoded path.

I did more tests, and it turned out that IE ignored cookies with path `/foo` for a literal request to `/foo`. A request for `/foo/` (with `Set-Cookie: key=val; path=/foo`) works though. Even with percent-encoded values.